# How can I achieve optimisation for a continuous sensor data stream query?

Tags: griddb

I'm working on an application that utilizes GridDB as its primary database for storing and retrieving large datasets. The application frequently performs complex queries on this data, and I'm looking to optimize query performance.

Specifically, I'm interested in understanding how to choose the optimal compression algorithm for numeric and timestamp data, configure compression ratios, and balance the trade-offs between storage size and query performance. Code examples demonstrating compression settings, compression benchmark results, and guidance on selecting compression techniques for different data types in GridDB would be greatly appreciated.